# conditional loading of jquery and jquery UI issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-statements

The following works perfectly:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

However, doing the same for Jquery UI (but with the change to window.ui - this should be right but I'm not 100% sure) does not work - actually it loads the local version every time not just when CDN file is not available (per Firebug):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.ui && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

It does load the local version when network is unavailable but also when the CDN version is loaded (which means unnecessary double loading).

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your load check just needs a little tweak. jQuery UI creates a `ui` object [under the jQuery (or `$`) object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L15), not under `window`.  So `window.ui` should be `window.jQuery.ui`, like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery.ui && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be stupid, but I prefer OR logic over AND for this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js"<\/script>'))</script>
```